# DoubleTap Event from Silverlight in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, touch

I am building a **.NET 4.0 WPF Application** with items that the user can both drag and drop and execute.

1. For the drag and drop, I am using the **Tap and Slide** (aka Tap and a Half): [Microsoft Surface Touch: Tap, swipe, and beyond](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/touch-mouse-and-search/using-touch-gestures-tap-swipe-and-beyond)
2. For the execute, I am using a **Double Tap**

Ran into conflicts between the two, since the tap and slide involved two `TouchDown Events`. I have a workaround, but it feels hacky (changed it to look for `TouchUp Event`) for the **Double Tap**.

What I really need is a `DoubleTap Event`.

I found [Silverlight UIElement.DoubleTap Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.doubletap(v=vs.95).aspx).

However, it seems that this Event is not there for WPF, unless I am just plain missing something.

Is there any sort of alternative for WPF?  Does anyone know why they would provide this event in Silverlight's `UIElement`, but not in WPF's `UIElement`?

Thank you,

Philip

Comment: As far as I know wpf doesn't have an explicit double tap event. But you can use single tap event (detect it as [SystemGesture.Tap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.systemgesture.aspx)) and check if it's happened twice in a row.

Comment: @IvanZub Thank you for sharing this information regarding the SystemGesture.Tap, I didn't even know about that event before.  I am looking into this. :-)

Comment: @IvanZub Your comment/answer was spot on and exactly what I needed.  Could you please copy your comment into an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know wpf doesn't have an explicit double tap event. But you can use single tap event (detect it as [SystemGesture.Tap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.systemgesture.aspx)) and check if it's happened twice in a row.